# .htacces implemented - URL not correctly refreshing

Tags: php, refresh

I am using .htaccess. I have a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^pg/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

One of my page has a URL: `http://domain.com/pg/page1`

In this page there is a meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=pg/page2'>
```

Now, when this page get refresh..the new url which is formed is: `http://domain.com/pg/pg/page2` i.e. `pg` is coming twice.

I have already specified a base href tag in header as:

```
<base href='http://domain.com'>
```

Why `pg/` is coming twice and how to get rid of it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you start the path with a forward slash (`'/'`), e.g. `'/pg/page1'`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can there be some other issues due to this?

Comment: Only if you later move the website into a subdirectory.  The preceding slash tells the browser (and, by extension, the web server, once the request is made) that the resource should be requested from the web root, not from the current folder.  If you ever move the site into a subdirectory (from the web-facing point of view, that is, e.g. www.example.com/my_sub_directory/pg/page1) you will need to specify that subdirectory after the forward slash but before the rest of the path.

Comment: Another issue coming is that I have a page at: http://smstongue.com/pg/d/help/faq and there are <a href='#1'> links. But on clicking this link it takes me to http://smstongue.com/#1 and not http://smstongue.com/pg/d/help/faq#1. I have used <base href="http://smstongue.com/"> in head and I think because of this it is happening. Please suggest what changes needs to be done.

Comment: The problem is your `<base>` tag, so you have a few options.  You can remove the `<base>` tag and use absolute paths, of course, or you can be a little more tricky.  I notice that your menu.js file includes a reference to jquery, although you're not including jquery on that page.  Without jQuery: `document.onreadystatechange = function () { var f = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]; var g = f.parentNode; g.removeChild(f); document.onreadystatechange = null; };` With jQuery: `$(function(){$('base').remove();});`.

Comment: In any case, however, it's related to the `base` tag, so that's what you need to focus on fixing.  You could always put the absolute path in the <a> link.

Comment: Also, thank you for bringing this comment to me because by researching it I learned that you don't have to use `<a name>` for an anchor, but can specify the id of an element you want to scroll to.  For posterity, here's the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)